# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

estoy haciendo un programa muy sencillo y practicamente esta terminado, solo que no me marca un error al momento de compilar.
El programa es el siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando python 2.7

Comment: Por favor tu código y error como texto y no como imagen amigo, pues asi no es posible reproducir el problema expuesto

Comment: No debes usar imágenes para insertar tu código ni el error arrojado. Pega ambas cosas y dales formato de código usando el botón del editor. Lee https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error, es tratar de leer o escribir variables inexistentes dentro de ese ámbito.
Cuando realizas la función **base**, o **cálculos**, realmente no estás utilizando tus variables definidas, sino que estas creando nuevas variables dentro de esas funciones.

Si quieres trabajar con variables que están fuera de dicha función, asegúrate de decirle al programa de donde provienen.

Para solucionar tu error, es muy fácil, simplemente añade global a las variables en cada funcion que necesites.

```
def datos():
    global base
    global altura
    base=float(input('Ingrese la base del rectángulo en centímetros: '))
    altura=float(input('Ingrese la altura: '))

def calculos():
    global perimetro
    global area
    perimetro=(base+altura)*2
    area=(base*altura)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, resolviste mi duda y tendré en cuenta lo que me has dicho

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Por que me da error al definir una variable global fuera de las funciones?

Comment: Las variables que generas fuera del contexto de una función ya se generan automáticamente como globales, sin embargo siempre que quieras llamarlas desde una función debes idicarle que es la variable global y no una local de esa misma funcion. Así es como funciona Python

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu duda, por favor no olvides marcarla como resulta de forma que si alguien tuviera el mismo problema sepa cual es la solucion^^